# Reuseable function for looping

Tags: c, inject, reusability

Question:
I want to create a reusable function, because in my code much line that use same code structure
The code using for example `` if { if { `Only here's the different` } } ``. Of course the pattern not same as this, this using as an example.
I've been code using framework such as Laravel, there's a directive called as `SLOT`
Is there any way I can inject code in the middle of for loop? Or anything same as `SLOT` inside C programming

Sample code:

```
void functionname() {
  for (int i=0; i < total_count; i++) {
    SELECT THE ITEM (i)
    if (a == b) return;
    if (c) {
      CODE INJECT HERE
    }
  }
}
```

Forget to mention before, a, b, c and so on from the coding above is getting from ITEM (i)

Comment: Have you heard of function pointers?

Comment: Yes, Have use the pointer before but not so expert in pointer. But I don't think the pointer what I'm looking for. Or do you has example of useful resource I can read about it (function pointer that related to this issue topic). GitHub / other StackOF could do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback. i.e. you should send a function pointer (i.e. the address of the function you want to execute) and use that pointer to execute that function inside your loop.

In the example below, p is a pointer to a function taking a  **const char** ***** for a parameter and returning an **int**.

```
int (*p)(const char *s) ;
```

NB: all functions passed as parameter, to be used as callback must have the same prototype (which is why such functions are often declared taking a generic pointer parameter void * to accept whatever you've got to send to the function).

So with your example and with functions taking void * as a parameter and returning void *, and with param defining a parameter that you want to feed to your function, this gives us the following code:

```
void functionname(void *(*func)(void *)) {
  for (int i=0; i < total_count; i++) {
    SELECT THE ITEM (i)
    if (a == b) return;
    if (c) {
      func(&param);
    }
  }
}
```

you can call your function wiht whatever function respecting the prototype... For instance:

```
void *my_custom_function(void *param) {
...
}
...
functionname(my_custom_function);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by KamilCik, use **function pointers**:

```
void functionname(void *fx)(void)) {
  for (int i=0; i < total_count; i++) {
    SELECT THE ITEM (i)
    if (a == b) return;
    if (c) {
      //CODE INJECT HERE
      fx();
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like

```
void foo(void) { puts("foo() called"); }
void bar(void) { puts("bar() called"); }

int main(void) {
    functionname(foo);
    functionname(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a concrete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
typedef void (*selector)(int, int *);
typedef void (*injector)(void);

void select1(int x, int *c) { printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, *c = x); }
void select2(int x, int *c) { printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, *c = x); }
void inject1(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }
void inject2(void) { printf("%s\n", __func__); }

void
functionname(size_t total_count, selector SELECT_THE_ITEM,
        injector CODE_INJECT_HERE )
{
        for (size_t i=0; i < total_count; i++) {
                int c;
                SELECT_THE_ITEM (i, &c);
                if (a == b) return;
                if (c) {
                        CODE_INJECT_HERE();
                }
        }
}

int
main(void)
{
        functionname(2, select1, inject1);
        functionname(3, select2, inject2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are great for this. You can `typedef` the function signatures you'd like to support. Example:

```
/* A signature for condition checking functions, taking a "void*" argument
   and returning true or false */
typedef bool(*cond_check_t)(void*);

/* A signature for functions to execute if a condition is met. This takes a
   "void*" argument but you decide what you need */
typedef void(*exec_t)(void*);
```

You can package these two in a `struct` to form a nice pair:

```
typedef struct {
    cond_check_t checker;
    exec_t executor;
} check_exec_t;
```

And with that, another `struct` to keep a bunch of these condition and executor pairs:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    check_exec_t *conditionals;
} cond_pack_t;
```

You then create support functions for adding checkers and executors and a function to processes one of these packaged checkers and executors.

```
cond_pack_t* cond_pack_create(size_t capacity) {
    cond_pack_t* cp = malloc(sizeof(*cp));
    if(cp) {
        cp->conditionals = malloc(sizeof(*cp->conditionals) * capacity);
        if(cp->conditionals) {
            cp->size = 0;
            cp->capacity = capacity;
        } else {
            free(cp);
            cp = NULL;
        }
    }
    return cp;
}

void cond_pack_destroy(cond_pack_t *cp) {
    free(cp->conditionals);
    free(cp);
}

bool cond_pack_add(cond_pack_t *cp, cond_check_t checker, exec_t executor) {
    if(cp->size == cp->capacity) return false;
    cp->conditionals[cp->size].checker = checker;
    cp->conditionals[cp->size].executor = executor;
    ++cp->size;
    return true;
}

void cond_pack_process(cond_pack_t *cp) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < cp->size; ++i) {
        if(cp->conditionals[i].checker(NULL)) { /* execute checker */
            cp->conditionals[i].executor(NULL); /* execute executor */
        }
    }
}
```

With that, a usage example could look like this

```
//---
bool some_check(void *foo) {
    return true;
}
void some_executor(void *foo) {
    printf("some_executor\n");
}

bool some_other_check(void *foo) {
    return false;
}
void some_other_executor(void *foo) {
    printf("some_other_executor\n");
}

int main() {
    cond_pack_t *cp = cond_pack_create(10);
    if(cp) {
        cond_pack_add(cp, some_check, some_executor);
        cond_pack_add(cp, some_other_check, some_other_executor);
        
        cond_pack_process(cp); /* run all the checkers / executors */

        cond_pack_destroy(cp);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1GT76h91d)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you ask by defining your "`CODE INJECT HERE`" as the body of a function, and passing a pointer to that function:

```
void functionname(void (*inject)(void)) {
  for (int i=0; i < total_count; i++) {
    SELECT THE ITEM (i)
    if (a == b) return;
    if (c) {
        inject();
    }
  }
}

void do_something(void) {
    CODE INJECT HERE
}

void do_something_else(void) {
    OTHER CODE INJECT HERE
}

int main(void) {
    functionname(do_something));
    functionname(do_something_else));
}
```

Do note, however, that this is not simple code injection in the same sense as a macro would provide.  In particular, the executions of `do_something()` and `do_something_else()` will not see the local variables of `main()` or of `functionname()`, and the `do_*` functions can return only from themselves, not from a caller further up the chain.  The former can be mitigated to some extent by passing parameters to the `do_*` functions (which they must be prepared to accept).

---

Another alternative would be to use a macro instead of a function to provide the common framework.  It would look something like this:

```
#define frame_it(x) do {                \
  for (int i=0; i < total_count; i++) { \
    SELECT THE ITEM (i)                 \
    if (a == b) return;                 \
    if (c) {                            \
        x                               \
    }                                   \
  }                                     \
} while (0)

int main(void) {
    frame_it(
        CODE INJECT HERE
    );
    frame_it(
        OTHER CODE INJECT HERE
    );
}
```

That keeps the `CODE INJECT HERE` code in the function using it, which might be advantageous if in fact each such piece of code is used in only one place.  It also allows both that code and the framing code to access the local variables of the function in which they appear, and to return from that function if desired.

However, macro programming has earned a mostly-deserved reputation for being error prone and difficult to read and debug.  Your particular need may be one that is well served by this approach, but do not choose this direction lightly.

Comment: Although I (almost) always like hedging with "almost certainly" and the like, "mostly-deserved" is being overly generous!